# What PHP function Wordpress use to download package?

Tags: php, wordpress

Just for curiosity, I want to know what PHP function (for eg. file_get_contents, copy etc) Wordpress use to download package? I know it Wordpress have a download_url function which use to upgrade its core package (if I am right).

I searched on the internet but didn't find what I want to know. 
(Please don't mention the procedure which is mentioned on Wordpress site.)

Comment: Have you traced the code back to what uses download_url()? Being able to trace it back yourself will be a massive boost to you

Comment: Why don't you have a look at Wordpress source code itself?

Comment: I tried to understand but I didn't get what is happening inside download_url(). It seems very advanced to me. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can figure out what it uses by reading the source code here:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.7/src/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L965

It appears to use a function called wp_safe_remote_get, which uses _wp_http_get_object.

That creates a WP_Http object...

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/http.php#L22

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-http.php

You then have this:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/class-requests.php#L357

Then we go to the get_transport function:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/class-requests.php#L181

This hints at using cURL or fsockopen. So that's it.

There's examples of how those work here:

http://php.net/manual/en/stream.examples.php

I would use the php `copy` function as its simpler and is less resource intensive as it doesn't copy the payload into memory.